# How to scale text buttons android?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

i want to develop an app like a calculator. The problem is, that the text buttons have to be in the same order on every device. I tried it like this but i doesn't work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:background="@drawable/neon_bg">



<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="8"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button11" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button10" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button14" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button15" />
```

How can i let the button scale to the size required for the screen, so the buttons have the same size in relation?

Thanks

Comment: you can use multiple .xml files for multiple screen resoulutions

or you can use weight for layout's width and height instead of dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `weight_sum` and `weight` property to achieve which you are looking.

For instance, here parent `ViewGroup` is `LinearLayout` whose `weight_sum` is 2 so in your case it would be 4 and child view group of it `RelativeLayout` whose `weight` is 1 so in your case also it would be 1 and instead of it you would have `Buttons` that's all.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2.0" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#0000FF" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It should solve your problem.